# Difference between normal customized event the static RoutedEvent

Tags: wpf, events

Please check the code below which defines the same scroll event in two different ways:

---------------------------------normal way--------------------------------------

```
  public event RoutedEventHandler CloseTab;
```

------------------------------static RoutedEvent---------------------------------

```
  public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseTabEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CloseTab", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CloseableTabItem));
  public event RoutedEventHandler CloseTab
    {
        add { AddHandler(CloseTabEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CloseTabEvent, value); }
    }
```

---

1.What's the difference between the normal customized event and the static RoutedEvent?

2.Why the event in the first way can be raised by a method like "if(CloseTab!=null){CloseTab(o,e);}",but in the second way ,it only can be raised by the UIElement.RaiseEvent() method?

3.I know this question must be very very silly,but it dose make me confused.
It is that Why the event in the first way can be raised by the "if(CloseTab!=null){CloseTab(o,e);}" method only in the class which the event is defined?And when it is outside the owner class,the event can only add or remove handlers with "+=/-=" ?

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

You implementation basics i.e. the way we raise each one differently, are correct.

But apart from that, as far as my knowldge on routed events goes...

1. The first is **NOT** a routed event. It is a simple CLR event declared with its type as the `RoutedEventHandler` delegate. When this event is raised it will not bubble \ tunnel up to the ancestor/child UI elements respectively.
2. At practical level, I guess if you try using the first one in `EventTrigger` it will not work.